# Automatic update of powerpoint graphs from a linked excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-excel-2016, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

So I've been having a bit of a problem recently, I somewhat solved it, but I'd love to see if anyone has a better suggestion.

I have created a powerpoint file with a bunch of graphs using the simple method of copying and pasting them from excel. Now this is all fine and dandy, however the links break each time I close the powerpoint, and I have to manually update each one. I won't use the method of copying then paste-special, paste link option, as this requires for me to keep the graphs in the source excel, which is a nuisance.

Through some digging around, I found a simple macro of updating all links in the powerpoint presentation. See below.

Sub Updatelinks()
ActivePresentation.Updatelinks
End Sub

While this does work, it only updates the graphs to the current source data, while going Design-> Refresh Data makes the graph dynamic, meaning if something is changed in the source data, the graph automatically changes aswell.

Does anyone have any idea how to create a macro to refresh all data, so that it dynamically updates? And if so, would there be a way to start the macro on startup?

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: I have a similar issue, it's strange no one gave any suggestion about it